# find the supremum and infimum of a set

Tags: real-analysis, maxima-minima, supremum-and-infimum, natural-numbers

find the inf/sup of the set A= { n $ \in   \mathbb{N} $  | $n^2-3n +1 $}

before finding the inf and sup  i checked for the first terms of this set, for n $\in $  {0, . . . 6}    we have  {1 , -1 , -7 ,5 , 11 ,19} $\subset A$

so i assumed that -7 may be the infimum so based on the defintion

-7 $\le$ a     $ \hspace{20mm } $   $ \forall a \in A$

-7 $\le$ $n^2-3n+1  \hspace{15mm}$   $ n^2 -3n +8 \geq 0   \hspace{15mm}  \Delta = 9-32 < 0 \implies \forall n   \hspace {1cm} -7 \leq a_n  \hspace{1cm}\forall a_n \in A  $

i don't realize how to  find the supremum ( i know it is + $ \infty$ but i dont know how to prove it, i tried with reductio ad absurdum but i failed finding a contradiction)

Comment: I see two ways: Either show that the sequence is eventually increasing, or show that any upper bound can be exceeded.

Comment: but there is no sequence, i am talking about a set, and i already stated in my answer that i could not find any contradiction so giving such an hint doesn't solve the problem

Comment: You may regard the elements of $A$ as the terms of the sequence $a_n = n^2 - 3n + 1.$

Comment: but doesn't the sequence behave differently compared to a set?

Comment: or i can just regard the set a  sequence and for example try to prove the sequence is monotonic eventually using induction there for there must exist a limit L that will be the supremum?

Answer (score 2):

The least troublesome way to show that your set $A$ doesn't have supremum is to argue that it isn't even bounded from above; recall that the supremum of a set of real numbers is the least upper bound of the set, which cannot exist if there's no upper bound.
Now, to show that there's no upper bound for your set $A$, we can argue by contradiction. Suppose $A$ has an upper bound, say $\alpha > 0$. Then we clearly have
$$3n-1 \geq 2 \qquad \text{ for all } n \in \mathbb{N} = \{1,2,3,\ldots\},$$
and so
$$n^2 - 2 \leq n^2 - (3n-1) = n^2-3n+1 \leq \alpha \qquad \text{ for all } n \in \mathbb{N},$$
which is equivalent to
$$n \leq \sqrt{\alpha +2} \qquad \text{ for all } n \in \mathbb{N}.$$
But this implies that the set $\mathbb{N}$ of natural numbers is bounded from above, which is absurd.